# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Code:

```
 set @FinalSet = 'SELECT * FRom dv) AS Rpt
     PIVOT(
     
     Max([FINAL_SCORE_AGREED])
     for PeriodMonth IN ([January],[February],[March],[April], 
 [May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November], 
 [December])
     
     )as Pvt

     Pivot(
     
         Max([NAME]) 
         FOR [NAME] IN (' + @columns + '))as Pvt2';

            execute(@FinalSet)
```

Comment: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql). There's a lot wrong with that query, and we have no way of running it to see what the problem is. I suggest you start with reading the sections in the article on parametrisation, proper quoting, and debugging. They should be all you need to fix the above. We can't run this above SQL, so we have no chance of really helping you here at the moment, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing either a comma or operator in the first section, causing both errors.

```
e.FirstName  e.LastName as [APPROVER_NAME],
```

SQL Server is trying to assign `e.LastName` as an alias for `e.FirstName`, which it cannot do because of the period, and then it's confusing itself with the second AS because it thinks you've already tried to give it an alias.

If you're trying to concatenate the strings, you can do this with the '+' operator.

```
e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName AS [APPROVER_NAME]
```

If not, then a comma should allow it to run regardless.

```
e.FirstName, e.LastName AS [APPROVER_NAME]
```